# How to detect declaration of class at compile-time?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I'm use some 3-rd party library at my project. After updating to new version of library I'm faced with errors.

One my class have method

```
virtual RTSPServer::RTSPClientSession* createNewClientSession(u_int32_t sessionId)override;
```

but in new version of library declaration of RTSPClientSession was moved into another class and renamed. Now correct name is

```
GenericMediaServer::ClientSession
```

I need a code which will be correctly compiles with all versions of library.

At gcc I use following code:

```
#ifdef RTSPServer::RTSPClientSession
    using ClientSessionClass = RTSPServer::RTSPClientSession;
#else
    using ClientSessionClass = GenericMediaServer::ClientSession;
#endif

class A
{
    .........
    virtual ClientSessionClass* createNewClientSession(u_int32_t sessionId)override;
};
```

but this not work in MSVC 2010.
How I can detect which declaration I should use?

UPD: code for gcc also don't work for old version of library :(

Comment: Branch your codes and keep two versions?

Comment: Sure about `#ifdef RTSPServer::RTSPClientSession`? That's neither a valid preprocessor symbol, nor seen from the preprocessor at all.

Comment: I agree with πάντα, I've very surprised that gcc is doing what you think it is.  You might see if an include or build file is defining that symbol, in which case you can replicate the behavior in msc.

Comment: Yes, I check code with #ifdef at old version of library and it's don't work.

Answer (score 2):

> *"How I can detect which declaration I should use?"*

You need to introduce some discriminator for the library version you're using with your current build configuration:

```
#ifdef OLD_LIBRARY_VERSION // Maybe the binding headers have some information like this.
                           // If not you have to select this manually, and provide the 
                           // setting with your project configuration.
   using ClientSessionClass = RTSPServer::RTSPClientSession;
#else
   using ClientSessionClass = GenericMediaServer::ClientSession;
#endif
```

Comment: Good variant, if developer of library can say in which version of library they are making this changes.

Comment: @DmitryBakhtiyarov _"if developer of library can say in which version of library they are making this changes."_ As mentioned, if they were honestly good developers, they should have left such `#define` you can use to bind with it. Otherwise, just kick them in the ass and require such. You still can manage yourself, binding explicitly.